# Find min based on criteria, not to include zero values then return Nth column

Tags: excel

I have this Excel 2013 array formula which appears to work fine to find cheapest rate based on comparing two ids from different sheets;

```
{=MIN((IF(DATASET!$A$2:$A$78956=A2,IF(DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956<>0,DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956))))}
```

I now need to return the supplier of the cheapest rate, who is situated in column AH of sheet DATASET.

I have attempted to bolt on an index match to the above formula to render the cell in question, however I'm getting a N/A.

Would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this conundrum :)

```
{=INDEX(DATASET!$AH$2:$AH$78956,MATCH(MIN((IF(DATASET!$A$2:$A$78956=A2,IF(DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956<>0,DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956)))),$Y$2:$Y$78956,0))}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or do you just need to adjust the end of your formula to show column AH like this:`{=MIN((IF(DATASET!$A$2:$A$78956=A2,IF(DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956<>0,DATASET!$AH$2:$AH$78956))))}`

Comment: @Kyle Column AH are the names of the contractors/Suppliers.  OP is looking to return the name where the value is the minimum in column Y that matches the ID in Column A.  So since AH is not number that formula will return an error.

Comment: You can try: `=INDEX(DATASET!$AH$2:$AH$78956,MATCH(MIN(IF((DATASET!$A$2:$A$78956=A2)*(DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956<>0),DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956)),IF((DATASET!$A$2:$A$78956=A2)*(DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956<>0),DATASET!$Y$2:$Y$78956),0))` as an array formula.  remeber that array formulas need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  The `{}` are put in by Excel when you hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter and not by the user.

Comment: I've just tried this and mixing arrays and index-match is working fine for me. Could you try using SUMPRODUCT instead?

Comment: @Jonathan I assume that the OP wants to return a string, as the Op stated that they are trying to get the supplier. If that is the case SUMPRODUCT will not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner good point and I hadn't thought of that - thank you.

Comment: Hi, I thought this formula was the answer , but it transpires the index is rendering duplicates... how I can stop this? 


`
 =IF(T2=0,"",INDEX(DATASET!$AH$2:$AH$1455,MATCH(MIN((IF(DATASET!$A$2:$A$1455=A2,IF(DATASET!$AI$2:$AI$1455<>0,DATASET!$AI$2:$AI$1455)))),DATASET!$AI$2:$AI$1455,0))) `

Tried @ScottCraner code but didn't work.